# Writing Dataframes to disk periodically instead of infinitely growing memory usage

Tags: python, pandas

I'm collecting a bunch of data from an ever increasing pool of sites in dataframes, processing that data, combining it and ultimately saving it to disk.

This has worked well so far but I'm now coming to the end of my server's memory capacity. Although the memory consumption is far greater than the size of my DFs (and there's definitely optimization that can be done there), to be able to scale this process at some point I will need to look at writing to disk and not having everything stored in memory. I might as well do this properly now, instead of optimizing something I will have to re-do at some point in the future anyway.

How would you structure a re-factor of this sort? My idea is:

1. Continue to use a dataframe per site
2. Process dataframe
3. Save to disk
4. Combine all saved DFs from disk into a single output file at the end of the run

Thanks

Comment: one useful suggestion could be to store your data in Parquet files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this same issue last week. The solution I came up with was batching.
I experimented on my machine, and found that 50,000 rows per dataframe is a good number. I keep writing to a dataframe until it reaches this number, and then I save it, add an index to the title, and move on to a new clean dataframe. I prefer to overwrite on top of the old one to avoid any issues with the grabage collector.

Combining the dataframes could be done with multiple ways that are light on the memory. For instance, to avoid loading all of them in the memory and concatenating them into a very big dataframe, you can simply seek to the end of the target file, write directly to it, and repeat.

This would not lead to any issues in the memory, as at any point in time, only 1 dataframe is loaded in the memory.

Comment: Thanks @Mina - I've been reading about pickling dataframes. Is this an option that could work here as well, and something that you considered?

Comment: @splotsh the gains from pickling is limited, and are mainly about file size on disk. So let's say you save 50% of the file size by using binary data instead of text, the file footprint on disk is smaller, but not in memory. I assume your problem was with the memory, so pickling would not really help here. Pickling would help your read and write dataframes faster though, but you lose the human-readability aspect

Comment: also please consider accepting the answer or upvoting it if you find it helpful. It helps both of us.

Answer (score 0):

Write data frames to sql.
Query the required and filtered data when needed.